# Angularjs routing ejs static files in "views" folder from "public" folder of express.js

Tags: node.js, express, gulp, mean-stack, ejs

Here is my project structure.
[image: Project-structure]

I am trying to call the ejs file (app > views > list.ejs) which is in "views" folder from the angular routing file (app > public > main.js) which is in "public" folder. But the list.ejs is not loading.

```js
/************main.js****************/
var fsApp=angular.module('chart-app');
fsApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when('/', {
 templateUrl: 'list.ejs',
 controller: 'listCtrl'
})

/*In my server.js server file I am calling the files in public folder this way: */
app.use('/static',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

```html
<!--In index.ejs (where my <ng-view></ng-view> is) I am including the link for static files:-->

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="/static/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/static/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="chart-app" class="container-fluid">
<div ng-controller="fairshareCtrl">
 <div class="row" ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Is there anything more I have to do on the server file? What am I missing?

Comment: remove `ng-controller="fairshareCtrl"` from `index.ejs` file

Comment: Removed. But only the index.ejs is loading. Not list.ejs...

Comment: I think the path of `templateUrl: 'list.ejs',` is wrong. try checked it again. maybe it should be like this `templateUrl: 'views/list.ejs',`

Comment: The reason this does not load is that your server is not catching all other routes . Try change to `app.get('/*' , ... )`

Comment: I gave the path as  templateUrl: '../views/list.ejs' . Still did not work..

Comment: @Thanh Tung: I changed it to app.get('/*',function(req,res{res.render('index.ejs');}); Still not loading :(

Comment: are you use html5 mode ? try add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in router and put  `<base href="/">` in head of html

Comment: and I see in your code , you not static folder view . Try change path of templateUrl too

Comment: Thanks. I added `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` and included '<base href="/"> in index.ejs. What do I need to the path to? I tried `../views/list.ejs` and `../list.ejs` but did not work

Comment: Also, in the console I can see that my angular app itself is not getting recognized. Got this error: **Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'chart-app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had to use `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public'));` to make ejs to lookup in `public`directory rather than in `views` directory

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what are you using at the backend but, when you render the ejs file from express you have to define the engine for the same.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

then you can use

```
app.get('*',function(req,res){
   res.render('index.ejs');
});
```

and keep all the angular side in a public folder.

OR You can just load html file rather then ejs via ejs

```
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index.html');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`public` folder can not access the files that outside that folder, i.e. other folders like `node_modules`, `views` `routes` etc. That is why you are not able to load `list.ejs` from your `angular` `main.js` or `angular-route.js` file.

`Views` are used by `express` to render the view template(ejs) based on the request sent to the `backend`. They cant be used for frontend routing. They can only be accessed by the exprss app, but not the public folder.

For frontend routing, you will need to store all the templates in your `public` folder only.

I will suggest that you create a `templates` folder in your `public` folder, and use that `address` in your angular routing.

```
public  
  --templates
     --list.html
  --angular-route.js
  --main.css
  --main.js
```

use it like this in your angular routing.

```
fsApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
 $routeProvider
 .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
    controller: 'listCtrl'
})
```

I think you might need to include ejs.js in your view file, to support ejs templating in frontend. Read [ejs getting started doc](http://www.embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html) for more information on how to do it.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: If I place my files in `public` folder how will ejs access the files? I guess ejs expects the files to be in `views` folder right?

Comment: all these will be templates only, which will be inserted in the view file using frontend routing(angular routing), thus it will be rendered. just try this, and see if it works. i am using it like this only, and it works for me. There is no way, you can access views folder from frontend.

Comment: Not working.. Since I am working on ejs and not html file.. `ejs` looks up for rendering files in `views` folder only. Is there any option to override this otherwise?

Comment: i think you might need to include ejs.js in your view file, to support frontend ejs templating.